# Редактирование предыдущих сообщений при создании телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть inline кнопки

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

При нажатии на `Информация о парковках` выводиться следующее

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Если выбрать `Тарифы на парковки`, то будет так

[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

Мне необходимо заменять старые сообщения новыми

Пробую через метод `edit_message_text`

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, text=text)
```

Получаю

[![введите сюда описание изображения][4]][4]

Удаляються inline кнопки с сообщением и 1 сообщение после кнопок заменяться на нужное

Как можно решить мою проблему?

Код

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def ans(c):
    if c.data == "pricingplansparking":
        for d in data:
            adress = d['adress']
            minimaltimeforpayment = d['minimaltimeforpayment']
            price = d['price']
            text = f"Адрес: {adress}\nМинимальное время для оплаты: {minimaltimeforpayment}\nЦена: {price}"
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, text=text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда Вы изменяете сообщение, Вам так же нужно передавать по новой кнопки, которые вы хотите видеть в сообщении. Сделать это можно, указав аргумент `reply_markup` в функции `edit_message_text`:

```py
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, text=text, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Вместо **keyboard** укажите Вашу переменную с клавиатурой, где вы храните кнопки.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно, смотря из описания вопроса - передавать в изменённое сообщение кнопки, а сейчас - отправлять новое.
bot.edit_message_text() заменяет сообщение, на которое кликнул пользователь по кнопке. Если Вам нужно отправить новое сообщение с такими же кнопками, когда пользователь нажал на одну из кнопок, то используйте функцию bot.send_message и передавайте параметр reply_makrup, как в примере выше.

Comment: Тогда так просто такое не реализовать. Вам нужно хранить айди каждого сообщения в базе, искать это сообщение и удалять его. А нужно ли это вам? Мне кажется, у Вас ошибка в построении логики работы вашего приложения. Проще всего - изменять текущее сообщение вместе с клавиатурой, либо отправлять новое, с такими же кнопками навигации

Comment: Смотрите. Пользователь нажал на кнопку, вы отправляете ему НОВЫЕ сообщения. Бот не может их просто так заменить, не зная их ID. Поэтому Вам нужно где-то хранить айди этих сообщений, находить их в боте и заменять. Но это много ненужной логики и лишняя нагрузка на БД. Поэтому я и сказал, что у Вас ошибка в построение приложения. Находить и заменять эти сообщения - решение такое себе.

Comment: Тогда в хэндлере удаляйте сообщение методом bot.delete_message(), отправляйте сообщение с кнопками и отдельной сообщение с данными парковки.